# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'updateItem'

Tags: python, arcpy

I am working on map automation using arcpy.

I need to add a legend on the map layout based on the layers added to the mxd.I am using the code below (as given on the tutorial):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Project\Data\Rivers.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrFile, "TOP")
styleItem = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("USER_STYLE", "Legend Items",                "NewDefaultLegendStyle")[0]
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
legend.updateItem(lyrFile, styleItem)
```

But everytime I run this code i get the following error:

```
Runtime error 
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'updateItem'
```

What could cause this error to appear?

Comment: `legend` is a list, so you can add elements to it with `append` method

Comment: Given that the code you've posted has a syntax error (3rd line from the end), the most likely problem is that you messed up when typing the code into your Python interpreter. Try it again.

Comment: Seems like you're missing a closing parentheses.. Third line from the end.

Answer (score 0):

> What could cause this error to appear?

Well, I am not familiar with arcpy, but it seems the 0th element of whatever `ListLayoutElements()` returns is a list which indeed has no `updateItem()` method.

You might want to `.append()` to the list, or you might want to have a different type of object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the same as ArcGIS Help example,
  http://resources.arcgis.com/zh-cn/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000006z000000 
I tested the example code and it ran correctly.

By the way, I am wondering if you had pasted your own code. Otherwise you probably encounter problem in line 2,4,6 rather than the last line.

As the user2357112 suggested, you'd better try it again with clean code.
 Or you can confirm the type of the variable "legend" just by  `print type(legend)`before the line
 `legend.updateItem(lyrFile, styleItem)`